# Filling a new SQL column using two other columns

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

I am trying to combine to rows in a table into one new row in a table. Specifically columns First_Name and Last_name into First_Last. I am having trouble getting my query to run due to the fact I am trying to do this for all entries in the table and not just 1 row. Any suggestions?

Current Code:

```
    update Name
set First_Last = (select First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name from Name)
```

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: what rdbms are you using? sql-server, mysql, sqlite?

Comment: The answer given is of course correct, but this process leads to a very badly designed table. You should consider creating a view of your table instead.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you intend updating all rows on the same table using the `First_Name` and `Last_Name` values for each row, it is as simple as (in Sql Server):

```
update MyTable
    set First_Last = First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name;
```

In most other RBDMS, you use the pipe `||` operator or the `CONCAT` function to combine text.

Note that most RDBMS also have the concept of a computed (sometimes called generated) column, which prevents the redundancy and synchronisation issues with storing a derived field:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable...
(

   First_Last AS first_name + ' ' + last_name
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your RDBMS but if you are using MySQL you can use the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
update Name 
set First_Last = concat(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name)
```

Comment: Im sorry. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Everytime I try the above code I get this error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: @Walcottjc no problem, you didn't specify so I figured I would add an answer for MySQL